# PHP code (which uses AWS S3 SDK) hangs on exceptions instead of erroring out

Tags: php, curl, exception, amazon-s3

I have a webapp whose architecture is fairly straightforward:

- HAproxy for public facing load balancers
- Webserver running Apache
- Internal API server running AWS S3 SDK
- MySQL database Server

My web app has a major issue. Basically my web app utilises the internal API server to perform some discrete functions related to documents (hence AWS S3).  The API works fine under normal conditions however if there's an error (e.g. file doesn't exist or insufficient permissions) then the PHP code hangs.  I've tested this from my web app and also via cURL and I can replicate the issue easily.

Basic usage pattern:

- Webserver initiates a POST cURL request to the API Server via IP address
- API Server verifies the requesting Web Server belongs to an IP whitelist for security purposes (over and above the security groups I'm using in AWS VPC to restrict traffic in the same way)
- API Server then initiates a request to AWS S3
- API Server belongs to an IAM Role which has access to a custom S3 policy which grants it the necessary permissions to S3

To summarise:

- If the filename and permissions are fine, everything works fine
- If the filename is wrong or insufficient permissions, the request hangs for 5-10 minutes (effectively rendering my web server unusable until the request times out)

This is worrying for two reasons:

- The S3 policy is already quite restrictive but I need to lock it down a bit further in the near future
- I don't want my whole site to die simply if something goes wrong, I want it to handle exceptions gracefully

I've tried using the API from my web app and via cURL and the same behaviour occurs (i.e. hangs for 5-10 minutes).

```php
    require '/var/www/html/private/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

    use Aws\Credentials\CredentialProvider;
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    $s3 = S3Client::factory(['version' => 'latest','region'  => 'ap-southeast-2',]);

    try
    {
        $s3->deleteObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $path,
            'Key'    => $in_filename
            ));
        $numResult=1;
    }
    catch (S3Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        $numResult=0;
    }
    echo $numResult;
```

If an issue occurs, I expect to output a 0 character, which will prompt me to investigate further and/or I can improve the code to ship exceptions off to a syslog or similar.

(Btw I'm setting $path and $in_filename values just fine, left those out of the code).

Comment: Is it a versioned or non-versioned s3 bucket? Do you catch anything if you try catch a generic \Exception? Is this supposed to delete multiple files or just one?

Comment: It's a non-versioned S3 bucket.  The same sort of hang occurs on other PHP APIs doing tasks like COPY or PUT if the permissions or filename (esp in the case of COPY) are wrong.  Delete one file only at a time.

Comment: It makes no difference if I change the catch line to Exception instead of S3Exception - the same issue still occurs.

Comment: Does the S3 library have any timeout settings? A ten-minute hang is very odd - curl defaults should be much lower than that.

Comment: Even if I set the timeout to a low value (lets say 5 seconds) then that'd mean my webserver would timeout (http504) any requests from other users until the API request had finished. Still not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue and it had to do with Xdebug (v3.0.2 with PHP 7.4.15), when extension is disabled the SDK throws the exception without hanging.